# How can I get my Intel 82945G/GZ video card to support more resolutions?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, resolution

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04,the screen resolution is stuck at 1920x1280.everything appears big,its not comfortable to look at. There is no such option about screen resolution.

I got into the displays setting. I've only 2 screen resolutions 1024x800,800x600.how can i add 1280x800 or other such resolutions?

lspci shows this:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2772] (rev 02)

[image]

This is what I got after [checking for drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver):

[image]

Comment: Ok getting there, we need to know what kind of video card you have next, can you look at this question and edit your question to add what kind of video card you have? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: heres what i've got http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/947653/
and heres the screenshot after additional driver:
http://minus.com/mbrnwXZbwJ/

Answer (score 2):

hey i've just downloaded the latest updates and switched off my PC.when i switched it on in the morning the resolutions are fine and everything looked great.
when i first installed 12.04 there were no updates and after checking for an hour i got them.
i guess it must be with the updates.
heres the screenshot.
[image: working screen resolutions]

thanks a lot :)