# Setting correct (16:9) screen resolution for a Philips 166V3LSB/00 LCD monitor

Tags: resolution

I have a Philips 166V3LSB/00 LCD monitor connected to a box with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

```
user@host:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
...
```

The monitor is supposed to support 1366x768 (16:9) but I cannot get System Settings/Displays to even offer anything but ubiquitous 1024x768 and 800x600.  I tried removing `~/.config/monitors.xml` and re-logging in but that did not help.

**Update (1):**

I tried forcing modeline to Xorg.conf (added `Modes "1366x768" "1024x768" "640x480"`), but as a result:

- resolution os still the same
- System Settings/Displays now offers *only* 1024x768 (it previously offered 800x600 as well)

Here is my current [xorg.conf](http://pastebin.com/Bp5pLCE5) and [Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/6xwXCGSY).

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you could try forcing a modeline in your xorg.conf file

be careful, if your card doesnt support, you can have some serious issues,
make sure you make a back up of that file before you begin to edit it.

check this out for more information: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

its possible, that your video driver does not support the resolution and aspect ratio that you desire.

Comment: Unfortunately even modeline did not help. I have updated OP

Comment: this is old but it mentions optimizing your graphics chipset: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1130582

Comment: check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125443/how-can-i-get-my-intel-82945g-gz-video-card-to-support-more-resolutions